# Making loop over shapefile attribute using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, 3d-analyst, for-loop

I have a polyline shapefile. The shapefile has a field called "NAME"
[image]

I would like to make a loop over each line (A,B,C,D,...).

This is the python code for only first line named "A"

`profileLine = WORK_DIRECTORY + r'\CrossSections_onlyA.shp' 
profileTargets = WORK_DIRECTORY + r'\DTM.tif'
OutTable = WORK_DIRECTORY + r'\OutTableA.dbf'
arcpy.StackProfile_3d(profileLine, profileTargets, OutTable)`

I don't know how to do it over all of them with a loop. Also I would like to save the table with the name of each Line. for example: OutTableA.dbf, OutTableB.dbf, OutTableC.dbf and so on.

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have presented?  In any event, I think your starting point should be to use `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the da.SearchCursor to iterate over each line/row of the profilelines and create a feature layer for each using objectid. Then pass this feature layer to StackProfile. One output folder will also be created for each output table.

```
import arcpy,os

WORK_DIRECTORY = r'C:\somefolder'
arcpy.env.workspace = WORK_DIRECTORY
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

profileLine = r'CrossSections_onlyA.shp' 
profileTargets = r'DTM.tif'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(profileLine,['OID@','Name']) as cursor:
    for oid,name in cursor:
        sql = """{0} = {1}""".format(arcpy.Describe(profileLine).OIDFieldName, oid)
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=profileLine, out_layer='templine', 
                                         where_clause=sql)
        OutTable = "OutTable{0}.dbf".format(name)
        OutFolder = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace,name)
        os.mkdir(OutFolder)
        arcpy.StackProfile_3d('templine', profileTargets, os.path.join(OutFolder,OutTable))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it works but ".dbf" was necessary.